# What is the effect of rotations to the signs in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, 3d, rotations

I'm not very knowledgeable in math, so please forgive me for any mistakes I make in my explanation of my issue. I am writing a script in a 3D application that mirrors these Matrices to the other side of the ZY global axis. The thing I care about is what is being negated as the object's axis is rotated.

In order to understand the math behind this, I am using a script that rotates the x-axis of an object in 90 degrees three times.

```
rotX 0: Matrix(v1: (0.975, 0.171, -0.141); v2: (-0.141, 0.97, 0.199); v3: (0.171, -0.174, 0.97); off: (210, 10, 10))
rotX 90: Matrix(v1: (0.975, 0.171, -0.141); v2: (-0.171, 0.174, -0.97); v3: (-0.141, 0.97, 0.199); off: (210, 10, 10))
rotX 180: Matrix(v1: (0.975, 0.171, -0.141); v2: (0.141, -0.97, -0.199); v3: (-0.171, 0.174, -0.97); off: (210, 10, 10))
rotX 270: Matrix(v1: (0.975, 0.171, -0.141); v2: (0.171, -0.174, 0.97); v3: (0.141, -0.97, -0.199); off: (210, 10, 10))
```

- I can see that the first 90° rotation is negating the `v2.z`, `v3.x`,
  and `v3.y`.
- The second 90° rotation, 180°, is negating the `v2.x`,
  `v2.y`, `v3.x`, and `v3.z`.
- The third 90° rotation, 270°, is negating
  the `v2.z`, `v3.x`, and `v3.y`.

Looking at these values, I cannot understand the pattern. I think that, because I am rotating in the X axis, that is the reason the `v1` Vector representing the x-axis is unaffected. The object isn't changing position so that is why `off`, the position vector, is not affected.

In order to write a function that will know which values to negate for each 90° rotation, I need to understand the math behind it, which is why I am here.

Can any kind souls out there please help me understand this or help me point me in a direction towards solving this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably looking for Euler angles. Rotations are typically done with matrix multiplication such as with the OpenGL format.

Comment: What do you mean by "mirrors the Matrices to the other side of the ZY axis"? Apply a reflection in the $zy$ plane after, before, or what? And what is the off vector? Where the axis is located?

Comment: Rotation by angle $\theta$ around the $x$ axis is described by $$\mathbf{R}_x(\theta) = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{matrix} \right]$$and for $\theta=90°$, $$\mathbf{R}_x(90°) = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$$so there is something crucial about the situation missing. As it stands, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Hello and thank you all for the responses. I will do my best to answer any questions to make this issue as clear as possible: "Mirrors the Matrices on ZY" would mean [reflecting the axes of the objects](https://imgur.com/a/Q1nmxjk). I'm not sure if after, before. Can you explain the difference it would have on the axes? The off vector is the position. [Here](https://developers.maxon.net/docs/Cinema4DPythonSDK/html/manuals/data_algorithms/classic_api/matrix.html) is more information about the Matrix class from my 3D app. Please let me know what else needs to be clarified. Thank you.

Comment: I am rethinking how to ask the question: I want to reflect the axes of two objects on either side of the ZY plane, whatever their relation (one might be rotated 90° in X, the other 90° in X & 180° in Z). If I put the objects in the reflected rotation and position I am seeking, I can see which matrix vectors need to be negated to achieve the effect when I apply one matrix to the other. If I understand the math of the rotation's affect on the matrix, I can mirror the objects regardless of their differences in axis orientation.

Comment: @DrPontchartrain rotation matrices have orthonormal columns and rows. This means they must have length $1$ and the dot product of any two distinct columns or rows is $0$. The determinant of such matrices is also $1$. If the transformation also has a reflection it will have determinant $-1$. Two reflections along different lines is a net rotation so this complicates the signs in more than one dimension.